# How can I copy the <td> value(Command column) by clicking the copy button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://preview.linuxcommand.dev/

This is my website I'm trying to build, So right now its static and not dynamic, So all are same command you see that. 
So I want when the copy button on the right side is clicked, It will copy the command text of that column.
I don't want to push a different ID of each . Without this, Is there any way to possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @abid-hasan IDs must be unique in your page. Change them to classes (`class="foo"` instead of `id="foo"`) or use different IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("table button")

function clickButton(){ 
  var myTemporaryInputElement = document.createElement("input");
    myTemporaryInputElement.type = "text";
    myTemporaryInputElement.value = this.parentNode.querySelector("pre code").innerHTML;

    document.body.appendChild(myTemporaryInputElement);

    myTemporaryInputElement.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");

    document.body.removeChild(myTemporaryInputElement);

}
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     buttons[i].addEventListener("click", clickButton);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That works with the ready function. :)